# How to choose sim through code in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing SMS application . How can I give option to the use for select the sim  option.
I am using :

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

for sending sms .